# Constrained Optimization in R package recommnedation

Tags: r, optimization

I need to do a optimization of the following function under the linear constraints.

The objective function is  [image]

Are there any package or function recommendations in R ?  Thank you!

Comment: Hi: I  think ravi's alabama package might do that. But I'm not positive so check out cran. Even better,  check out the R optimization task view. That's quite comprehensive.